# Infer the interface of an object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, module, interface, initialization

Suppose I have a TypeScript interface in a module, and also a function that return an initialized object of that interface:

```
export default interface Foo {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    cars: number;
};

export function newFoo(): foo {
    return <Foo>{
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        cars: 0
    };
};
```

The problem is that I'm typing all the fields **twice**, and it's not only boring, but also **error-prone**.

I can't really use `return <Foo>{};` because there are cases of objects being members of other objects, so I'll have missing properties and `undefined` pops out.

I could check if the property exists when calling it, but since the property doesn't have the `?`, it means it's mandatory, so it's supposed to be there.

So, is there a better way to write the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reverse the way you type your `Foo` and function, and have `Foo` be whatever is the return type of `newFoo`:

```
export type  Foo = ReturnType<typeof newFoo>

export function newFoo() {
    return {
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        cars: 0
    };
};
```

If you want some members to be optional or not initialized by `newFoo` you will have to do a bit of work to add those in, although this might be overkill for complex scenarios:

```
export type  Foo = ReturnType<typeof newFoo>

export function newFoo() {
    const optionalInitiazlised = {
        optionaButInited: ""
    }

    return  Object.assign(optionalInitiazlised as Partial<typeof optionalInitiazlised>,
        {} as { optionalProp?: string }, {
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        cars: 0
    });
};
```